# About Node serving dynamic pages

Tags: node.js, angularjs, dynamic

I am doing a tech test for a job (Web Development) and in the test I need to get data from an API and there is this conditions for the **server**:

- Focus on client-side (AngularJS)
- nodeJS
- **The server must not serve dynamic pages**

My question is: Should I call the API directly using Angular? Or I can get the data from API using the node server?

What does **"The server must not serve dynamic pages"** mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is a tech test, I don't think it's a good idea to answer your first question. The assessors are likely very curious about your answer. Good luck!

As for, "The server must not serve dynamic pages", this just means you can only server static HTML from the web server. That is, you can't merge data into your HTML on the server side. No template engines. If I browse to a URL with a view, that view should always return the same HTML.

The server can also serve raw data

The trick is, you can change HTML in the browser based on the data. All dynamic behavior happens in the browser.